# How to make the a href fill the entire tab menu without losing the original size and shape?

Tags: html, css

[image][image]
[image]
I want to have the entire tab menu to be clickable. In order to do that, I need the "a href" to fill the entire tab but doing so I lose the exact size and shape I want. I'm trying to accomplish by adding the `:not(#sub_menu ul il)` to the main ul, il{} css styles but it throws the portions out of whack.

So how can I accomplish this in HTML & CSS? Also, the bottom border is still viewable, so how can I fix this as well? Thank you

Adding `:not(#sub_menu ul li)` to the main p, il settings.
Then increasing the padding by 5px to "10px 20px" in #sub_nav ul li #selected.

Home Page

```
<body>
<main>

    <h3>Home</h3>

    <nav id="sub_nav">
    <ul>
    <li id="selected"><a href="tabmenu.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="tabmenu_away.html">Away</a></li>
    </ul>

    </nav>
</body>
```

Away Page

```
<body>
<main>

    <h3>Away</h3>

    <nav id="sub_nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="tabmenu.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="selected"><a href="tabmenu_away.html">Away</a></li>
    </ul>

    </nav>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#sub_nav {
float: left;
width: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#sub_nav ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#sub_nav ul li {
display: inline;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#sub_nav ul li a {
padding: 5px 15px;
color:  inherit;
text-decoration: none;
border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
}
#sub_nav ul li#selected {
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
main {
margin-bottom: 1px;
padding: 1px;
height: 4000px;
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
}
main ul {
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}
main p, li {
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put <a> tag in <button> tag ( or <button> in <a>)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works and it's easier to code. Plus, I made the button flat as it were plain HTML. Is it possible to do the same without the button or is it too complex? Thank you.

Comment: I've tried the <button> inside <a> tag approach as suggested above but I miss the tab menu look. Is there anyway to accomplish this with buttons? Thank you.

Comment: button{
  background:none;
  border:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
Try this way to make button flat

Comment: Thanks, I had the flat look but forgot about the cursor. Anyway to make this a tab menu?

Comment: :D ? What is your problem? You can post your code into jsfiddle.net and 
I will easily visualize your problem. My English is not good enough to understand you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/donfontaine12/3ocadx7L/3/#&togetherjs=aajTPe4uDN